# How to store dataframe, view in tuple in spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I am trying to get the data from MongoDB in parallel and store all dataframes, view names in a collection so that I can refer them back.

For this, I created a collection where I am trying to store dataframes and views. I am getting error appending element to a collection. I tried using Vector, List, Seq. But nothing seems to be working for me.

Is there a way to handle such problems?

```
var mongoFrames = Nil

for(c <- collections) {
    var connectionString = connectionInt.setCollection(c);
    var dframe = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri", connectionString).load()
    var view = dframe.createOrReplaceTempView(c);
    var mongoQuery = s"select * from $c where tuid in (${tuidIn.mkString(",")})";

    var tup = (c, dframe, view, mongoQuery)
    mongoFrames += tup
}

for(v <- mongoFrames) yield spark.sql(v._4).collect() // load data from source into spark
```

**Update**

When trying to use +:, I am getting following error

> error: value +: is not a member of (String,
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, Unit, String)
> mongoFrames +: tup

Comment: does [this](https://rextester.com/MQS25508) do what you are looking for?

Comment: scala collections are immutable, so you need to reassign to a variable each time you’re appending or prepending to them. The operators are `:+` or `+:`.

Comment: @James I couldn't understand what exactly the link is trying to show. I am trying to fix issue with this `mongoFrames += tup`

Comment: If I have to use new variable name everytime, how would I be able to iterate over multiple collections. Looping over the collection seems to be the only solution to me. But it's not working somehow.

Comment: https://rextester.com/MQS25508 this is for the iteration.

Comment: write it as `mongoFrames :+ tup`, each time reassigning the result to `mongoFrames`

Comment: @James Updated the question. I tried `:+` syntax and it gives an error.

Comment: The scala compiler is wrongly inferring the type of `mongoFrames`. Have you tried explicitly writing its type? `var mongoFrames: Seq[Tuple4[String, Unit, String, String]] = Seq.empty`

Comment: Can you please write the type of `tup` in here? I want to know the types of `dFrame` and `view`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235829/discussion-between-shantanu-gupta-and-james).

Comment: I added more explanation about the iteration part to the answer. If you need to create a new collection as a result of this iteration, though, you can you use `map` instead of `foreach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as:

```
var mongoFrames: Seq[Tuple3[String, DataFrame,String]] = Seq.empty
```

and

```
var tup: Tuple[String, DataFrame, String] = (c, dframe, mongoQuery)

mongoFrames = mongoFrames :+ tup
```

then

iterate over it

```
for(v <- mongoFrames) yield spark.sql(v._3).collect()
```

**Edit 1:**

a more idiomatic way of iterating over the collection in this case is to write:

```
mongoFrames.foreach(spark.sql(_._3).collect())
```

using the anonymous function.

This is short for:

```
mongoFrames.foreach(mongoFrame => spark.sql(mongoFrame._3).collect())
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
var mongoFrames = List.empty[(String, DataFrame, Unit, String)]

for(c <- collections) {
//...
mongoFrames = mongoFrames:+ tup
}
```

Don't add variable of createOrReplaceTempView to tuple, it's of no use since method returns Unit. You can use access that temp view with it's name within SparkSession.

Comment: Your answer is correct as well. However @James was on chat session with me who helped me debug multiple issues with the errors. So marking his answer correct.